# How to read a large disk(like 1 ,2 TB) using ATA commands through DeviceIoControl funtion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, disk, ata

I want to read a large capacity disk using ATA commands sending though DeviceIoControl(). Sending commands using `ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX` structure is the main problem. Actually `CurrentTaskFile[]` arary of `UCHAR` type is not able to send a sector no greater than 16777215.

```
CurrentTaskFile[2] = 0xFF;
CurrentTaskFile[3] = 0xFF;
CurrentTaskFile[4] = 0xFF;
```

That is
`CurrentTaskFile[2] = 0xFF`  is Sector number register,
`CurrentTaskFile[3] = 0xFF`  is Cylinder low register,
`CurrentTaskFile[3] = 0xFF`  is Cylinder High register.

Now what to do if i want to read sectors no more than 16777215 (If I want to read a 1 TB disk's last sector). How to send sector no more than 16777215. Actually i have to read disk with capacity upto 4 TB.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `CurrentTaskFile[5]` which is Device/head register. Its range [depends on the disk capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#LBA-assisted_translation), for example for 4Tb disk it's from `0` to `127`. So the maximum number of addressable sectors for that disk is `256*256*256*128 == 2147483648` which seems enough.

Comment: Thanks @AntonSavin for your help. But i can't understand how to use CurrentTaskFile[5](Device/head) register with other  registers. Can you discribe how to read sector no more than 16777215 with the combination of all others registers (CurrentTaskFile[2], CurrentTaskFile[3], CurrentTaskFile[4] ). Please help.

Comment: @Sam I don't quite understand your question. Just set the values accordingly (sector number, cylinder number and head number) and read whatever sector you want.